# PHP Facebook graph API search cURL - no results

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I've got a problem with the facebook graph API.
I'm trying to do a search through the posts on facebook filtered on a keyword, but I can't seem to fetch the results.
When I copy my url in a browser, it works fine.

I think it has something to do with my cURL parameters, i'm pretty new to this.

```
<?php
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?&type=post&locale=en_US&q=".$keyword;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $result;
?>
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with this, or anyone who knows a different solution to fetch search results from facebook.

Comment: Any error messages? What's in $result? What is HTTP response code? Or even better, set CURLOPT_HEADER to 1 and check response headers.

Comment: No error messages. Turning CURLOPT_HEADER to 1 does nothing at all :s All I get a white page. There is nothing in $result, that's the problem. I thought that my results of the query would be in $result. I don't know about the HTTP response code. Grtz and thanks in advance.

Comment: Change "print $result;" to "var_dump($result)" and check the output.

Comment: If there is no output you should change your error_reporting settings: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Changing "print $result;" to "var_dump($result)" gave me this result: boolean false. I do found a stupid pasting error in my url, but fixing that doesn't change anything. I've also added error_reporting(E_ALL); to my code, but it still gives "boolean false" as only error :s

Comment: Hmm, how strange. "var_dump($result);" gives me <boolean false>. This means that $result is a boolean with value false. It should contain data like this: {
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "5XXXXXXX_10151310540011017",
         "from": {
            "name": "KXXXX XXXXX",
            "id": "55XXXXXXX6"
         },

Comment: Try to change $keyword to urlencode($keyword)

Comment: I tried to do that, if I change "$keyword" to "urlencode($keyword)" in the url, then I still get the "boolean false". If I change "$keyword" while retrieving my postdata I get the following error:  Fatal error: "Can't use function return value in write context in C:\wamp\www\facebook\search.php on line 6"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are trying to reach site through HTTPS, you should turn off SSL verification, or add certificate to verify with. Details here: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Quick fix:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Or you can just change your url to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?&type=post&locale=en_US&q=
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it :D This might come in handy for my twitter app also. (How can i give you plus points for answering my question ? )