# graph api returns false with curl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

this is my code:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '?access_token=' . $access_token;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

$response = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);
```

when i do var_dump($response) it shows bool(false).
but when i use the same url from chrome the request works fine.
what am i doing wrong?

p.s.
i'm using curl and not the facebook sdk because i get the id and access token from a third party, and i myself don't have an app id and app secret (because the users are not logging in to my application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Facebook graph API search cURL - no results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393898/php-facebook-graph-api-search-curl-no-results)

Comment: i looked there, the answers there didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following and see if it works

```
$data = file_get_contents(urlencode($url));
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: You can check https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php  how the CURL request is sent by facebook SDK, probably you are missing some CURL options.

Comment: i just tried to do that but it failed because the filename was too long.

Comment: hmm here is similar issue like yours you may check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203310/how-to-use-curl-in-facebook-graph-api-request